# Regex to find string within square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I need to create three regular expressions to extract the multiple words within square brackets , using the preg_match_all ()

example

Input string:

> Lorem [ipsum] dolor sit [[amet]], nam you dolores detracto definitionem. Et admodum fabellas patrioque here, offendit an obstinate sea, vis at [[summo]] alienum cotidieque. Quo tollit dolores cu viderer [Theophrastus] to vix. Cum homes erroribus to assueverit, putant vocent democritum eum ut ipsum nec timeam and Persius. Putant suscipit abhorreant jus cu. Pri doctus feugiat facilisis not. [[[East]]] in sint malis, and Equidem harassment inciderint sea, [[[vocibus]]] id mentitum sea.

1 . desired output for single brackets

```
[0 ] => Array
        (
           [0 ] => ipsum
           [1 ] => Theophrastus
       )
```

2 . desired output for double square brackets

```
[0 ] => Array
       (
           [0 ] => amet
           [1 ] => summo
       )
```

3 . desired output for triple square brackets

```
[0 ] => Array
       (
           [0 ] = > East
           [1 ] => vocibus
       )
```

Appreciate any help !

Comment: Do your double & triple `[[` actually have whitespace between them? like `[ [ amet ]]` ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski there is no whitespace like these [ [ amet ]] just a write error.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(\s*[\w]*\s*)\]/", $input, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/134467)</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't produce the output OP wants: "*I need to create three regular expressions to extract the multiple words within square brackets*"

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

for 1

```
preg_match_all('/[^\[]\[([^\[].*)\]/U', $text, $matches)
```

for 2

```
preg_match_all('/[^\[]\[\s?\[([^\[].*)\]/U', $text, $matches)
```

for 3

```
preg_match_all('/[^\[]\[{3}([^\[].*)\]/U', $text, $matches)
```

[demo](https://eval.in/134539)

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP wants (particularly the second one and third; the results contain the brackets; see [demo](https://eval.in/134472)).

Comment: you are right, i have willingly delete whitespaces betweeen **[ [**, did you really mentioned them?

Comment: What? Did you take a look at the demo?

Comment: take it easy man, i really just try to help.

Answer (score 0):

This not-so-readable looking regex should work:

```
$s = 'Lorem [ ipsum ] dolor sit [[ amet ]] , nam you dolores detracto definitionem . Et admodum fabellas patrioque here , offendit an obstinate sea , vis at [[ summo ]] alienum cotidieque . Quo tollit dolores cu viderer [ Theophrastus ] to vix . Cum homes erroribus to assueverit , putant vocent democritum eum ut ipsum nec timeam and Persius . Putant suscipit abhorreant jus cu . Pri doctus feugiat facilisis not. [[[ East ]]] in sint malis , and Equidem harassment inciderint sea , [[[ vocibus ]]] id mentitum sea .';

if (preg_match_all('/(?<!\[)\[(?!\[)([^]]*)\](?!\[)/', $s, $m))  // single [...]
   print_r($m[1]);

if (preg_match_all('/(?<!\[)\[\[(?!\[)([^]]*)\]\](?!\[)/', $s, $m)) // double [[...]]  
   print_r($m[1]);

if (preg_match_all('/(?<!\[)\[\[\[(?!\[)([^]]*)\]\]\](?!\[)/', $s, $m)) // triple [[[...]]]
   print_r($m[1]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  ipsum
    [1] =>  Theophrastus
)
Array
(
    [0] =>  amet
    [1] =>  summo
)
Array
(
    [0] =>  East
    [1] =>  vocibus
)
```